# Is it possible to get more screen real-estate in explorer in windows 8?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8

With the new file explorer in [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) it seems there's less screen real-estate than there used to be, mainly because of the new ribbon interface.

Perhaps it's me, but is there a way of increasing the amount of the window dedicated to viewing the folders and files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can simply minimise the ribbon:

   [image]
2. To always start Explorer with the ribbon in a minimised state, in Group Policy Editor (`Start / Run / gpedit.msc`), go to `Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Explorer`, double-click on `Start Windows Explorer with Ribbon minimized` and set it to `Enabled`:

   [image]
   [image]
3. There are various system file hacks that allow you to disable the ribbon completely, but I do not recommend them.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are referring to the ribbon - rightclick on the top, and select minimize ribbon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply press <kbd>F11</kbd> to go full screen. When you want to revert back, press it again.

Comment: nice tip. didn't know :)